# Computational indistinguishability with Example

Tags: provable-security, distinguisher

> Based on computational indistinguishability definition no PPT
>   algorithm can distinguish $X$ from $Y$, where $X=\{X_n\}_{n \in N}$
>   and $Y=\{Y_n\}_{n \in N}$ are ensembles of probability distributions
>   and $X_n$, $Y_n$ are probability distributions over $\{0,1\}^{p(n)}$
>   for some polynomial $p(.)$.

The above definition is not clear to me. Can anyone explain that with a clear example (e.g. roll a die or flip a coin). As the examples for the pevious posts about the same topic are not very clear.

Side note: I believe there is a lack of clear explanation and examples in the literature about this topic. So any good example would help the other learners too!

Comment: Can you define what a PPT algorithm is?

Comment: @kodlu  That's probabilistic polynomial-time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any $n \in \mathbf{N}$, let $X_n$ be a random variable which always equals $n$, and $Y_n$ be a random variable which equals $n$ or $n+1$ each with probability $1/2$. Then the probability ensembles $X = \{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ and $Y = \{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ are *not* computationally indisinguishable. A possible distinguisher is an algorithm $D$ which, on input $(y, 1^n)$, outputs $1$ if $y = n$ and $0$ otherwise. We then have $\mathsf{Pr}[D(X_n, 1^n) = 1] = 1$ for all $n$ because $X_n$ always equals $n$. On the other hand, we have $\mathsf{Pr}[D(Y_n, 1^n) = 1] = 1/2$, hence
$$\left| \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n, 1^n\right) = 1\right] - \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n, 1^n\right) = 1\right]\right| = \frac{1}{2},$$
which is constant and thus not negligible. I can't think of any simple example of probability ensembles which *are* computationally indistinguishable, except trivially if they are identical or just assumed to be indistinguishable. Indeed, constructing probability ensembles which are non-trivially computationally indistinguishable is in a way what cryptography is all about...

---

Actually, here's an example (although it could reasonably be considered trivial as well). As above, $X_n$ always equals $1^n$. $Y_n$ is the output of the following algorithm on input $1^n$:

1. Throw $n$ coins.
2. If the coins are all $0$, output $0^n$. Otherwise output $1^n$.

Thus $Y_n$ equals $0^n$ with probability $2^{-n}$ and $1^n$ with probability $1-2^{-n}$. I claim that they are computationally indistinguishable. Intuitively, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are identical except when $Y_n = 0^n$, but because this happens with negligible probability, no algorithm is able to distinguish them with non-negligible probability. (Note that this applies to all algorithms, not just PPT ones.)

Let $D$ be any algorithm, we want to estimate
$$\left|\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] - \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\right]\right|.$$
We remark that, conditioned on $Y_n \ne 0^n$, $(X_n,1^n)$ and $(Y_n,1^n)$ are identically distributed: they always equal $(1^n,1^n)$. Hence,
$$\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\middle|Y_n \ne 0^n\right] = \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right].$$
Using this, we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\right]
  &= \underbrace{\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n = 0^n\right]}_{\ge 0}
     + \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\ge \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\ge \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \middle| Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \cdot \mathsf{Pr}\left[Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\ge \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] \cdot \left(1-2^{-n}\right), \\
\end{align*}
$$
hence
$$\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] - \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] \le \underbrace{\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right]}_{\le 1}\cdot 2^{-n} \le 2^{-n}.$$
On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\right]
  &= \underbrace{\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n = 0^n\right]}_{\le \mathsf{Pr}\left[Y_n = 0^n\right]}
     + \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\le \mathsf{Pr}\left[Y_n = 0^n\right]
     + \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \wedge Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\le \mathsf{Pr}\left[Y_n = 0^n\right]
     + \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1 \middle| Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \cdot \mathsf{Pr}\left[Y_n \ne 0^n\right] \\
  &\le 2^{-n} + \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] \cdot \left(1-2^{-n}\right), \\
\end{align*}
$$
hence
$$\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] - \mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(Y_n,1^n\right) = 1\right] \ge \underbrace{\mathsf{Pr}\left[D\left(X_n,1^n\right) = 1\right]}_{\ge 0}\cdot 2^{-n} - 2^{-n} \ge -2^{-n}.$$

(For those studying the book of Katz-Lindell, this is similar to Exercise 7.1.)

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer.  I'm wondering whether the follwong statement is correct. Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$  be two random variables that can take on any value,$v_n$ where $0 \leq v_n \leq n$, then the probability ensembels $X=\{X_n\}_{n \in N}$ and $Y=\{Y_n\}_{n \in N}$ **are computationally indistinguishable**.

Comment: You have not specified the probability distributions of $X_n$ and $Y_n$. If they are both uniformly distributed, then yes, the probability ensembles are trivially indistinguishable, since they are identical.